# Calling a method only once with multiple threads

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, thread-safety

I have a web application which serves a lot of requests at the same time. 
In one of the app's API methods, I have a method - methodA(). In this method, I have a call to another method - doSomething(). 
I have a scenario in which I want the first call to methodA() will run the doSomething() method in a separate thread, but at this time, if another call to methodA() has been called, don't run the doSomething() method (because its still running by another thread) and just continue with the rest of methodA().

```
methodA() {
 .
 .
 doSomething() // In a new thread
 .
 .
}
```

I've considered using atomic boolean as a flag but I'm not sure if it's the best idea.

```
    private final AtomicBoolean isOn = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    methodA() {
        .
        .
        if (isOn.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
                     Runnable doSomethingRunnableTask = () -> { 
                         doSomething(); };
                     Thread t1 = new Thread(doSomethingRunnableTask);
                     t1.start();
                     isOn.set(false);
        }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [ReentrantLock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html). The lock will only allow one thread at a time, and its [tryLock()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html#tryLock--) method will return immediately with true or false depending on whether the lock was acquired.

```
ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();

methodA() {
    ...
    if (lock.tryLock()) {
        try {
            doSomething();
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

If you want to execute `doSomething()` in another thread, and you do not want to block any of the calling threads, you could just go with something similar to what you initially thought about.

```
AtomicBoolean flag = new AtomicBoolean();

methodA() {
    ...
    if (flag.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
        // execute in another thread / executor
        new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                doSomething();
            } finally {
                // unlock within the executing thread
                // calling thread can continue immediately
                flag.set(false);
            }
        }).start();
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! If I want doSomething() to run in a new thread, should I wait it finish its run before calling the unlock?

Comment: @OLY Yes, but then you have to decide whether you want the lock to be held by the calling thread or the executing thread. If the lock is held by the calling thread, it will be blocked until `doSomething()` finishes.

Comment: I understand but if I wait till the thread that runs doSomething() will finish, I lose the point of the asynchronous. In the other hand, I really don't want that main thread will call the unlock method before the doSomething() method finish. Is there any way to solve it?

Comment: @OLY Added another solution that is similar to your initial idea. This won't block any thread and only lets one thread execute `doSomething()` at a time.

Comment: I think this is what I've been looking for! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use ReentrantLock and it's `tryLock` method. From docs of [`ReentrantLock::tryLock`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html#tryLock--)

> Acquires the lock only if it is not held by another thread at the time of invocation.
>
> If the current thread already holds this lock then the hold count is incremented by one and the method returns true.
>
> If the lock is held by another thread then this method will return immediately with the value false.

So you could create such lock in your service as a field so that Threads that invoke your `methodA` will share it and then :

```
public class MyService {
    private ReentrantLock reentrantLock = new ReentrantLock();

    public void methodA() {
        if(reentrantLock.tryLock()) {
            doSomething();
            reentrantLock.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT** :
Here lock will be held by calling Thread and this thread will wait for the submitted task to finish and then unlock the lock :

```
public class MyService {
    private ReentrantLock reentrantLock = new ReentrantLock();
    
    private ExecutorService pool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    
    public void methodA() {
        if(reentrantLock.tryLock()) {
            Future<?> submit = pool.submit(() -> doSomething()); // you can submit your invalidateCacheRunnableTask runnable here.
            try {
                submit.get();
            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                reentrantLock.unlock();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also remember that I used threadPool in this example so this pool needs to be closed appropriately.

Comment: Thanks! If I want doSomething() to run in a new thread, should I wait it finish its run before calling the unlock?

Comment: It all depends on what you want to achieve, however if requirements are like this, you would have to wait for the thread to finish and then unlock the lock, because there might be possibility that a thread will unlock but the thread created in for doSomething method has not finished yet.

Comment: I understand but if I wait till the thread that runs doSomething() will finish, I lose the point of the asynchronous. In the other hand, I really don't want that main thread will call the unlock method before the doSomething() method finish. Is there any way to solve it?

Comment: But only the thread that holds the lock and actually created the new task somehow will wait, other threads will not be affected because they will not be able to acquire the lock.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, the thread that holds the lock is the thread that runs the doSomething() method and it will have to wait until that method will finish to unlock the lock. I wonder if there is a way to avoid its waiting also.

Comment: No, the thread that holds the lock is the thread that invoked `methodA` and this thread acquires lock, and if he succededs he submits a task to a ThreadPool and this task executes in another  thread owned by a ThreadPool. Then the thread that invoked methodA will wait for the task to finish and when it finishes or gets interrupted - the thread that invoked methodA will release the lock. So other threads that can invoke methodA will be able to process with methodA if the lock is held by some other thread.

Comment: So the thread of methodA will wait to the new thread (from pool) that runs doSomething() to finish. It means that it will not be asynchrony because the main thread that runs methodA will not run the rest of the method at the same time. Correct? If so, is there any way to overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using some kind of explicit lock, I would suggest you use a [blocking queue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html). The advantage I see is that you will not need to spawn a thread repetitively if/when there is need. You will only need to spawn a thread once that will only handle all the *doSomething*.

**Scenario:**

When *methodA* is called, it puts the necessary information for your dedicated thread into a BlockingQueue and keeps going. A dedicated thread will *poll* the information from the BlockingQueue (blocking on an empty queue). When some information is received in the queue, it runs your *doSomething* method.

```
BlockingQueue<Info> queue;

methodA() {
    //...
    queue.add(info);
    // non-blocking, keeps going    
}


void dedicatedThread(){
    for(;;) {
        //Blocks until some work is put in the queue
        Info info = queue.poll(); 
        doSomething(info);
    }

}
```

**Note:** I assumed that type *Info* contains the necessary information for method *doSomething*. If however you do not need to share any information, I would suggest you use a Semaphore instead. In this case, methodA would put tickets in the semaphore and the dedicated thread would try to draw tickets, blocking until some tickets are received.